How can I use web material 3 components in a code that uses react typescript + vite
Is it possible to use web material 3 Google components in React TypeScript + Vite ?
I tried to use it as follows
import '@material/web/checkbox/checkbox.js';

function App() {

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 16 }}>
      <h1>Checkbox com Material Web 3 no React</h1>
      <md-checkbox id="checkbox1">Checkbox Material 3</md-checkbox>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I get error
Property 'md-checkbox' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Is it possible to use react typescript + vite?

You can achieve it by passing your Material component as a string to your react app but you should be concerned that it will raise some security concerns.
here is a example code:
import "@material/web/button/filled-button.js";
import "@material/web/button/outlined-button.js";
import "@material/web/checkbox/checkbox.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `<label>
                    Material 3
                    <md-checkbox checked></md-checkbox>
                   </label>
                   <md-outlined-button>Back</md-outlined-button>
                   <md-filled-button>Next</md-filled-button>`,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



Any way to do this without using this methodology? Because I can have problems with XSS attacks

Yes, you can! Please check out 'Dompurify'
